# iPhone - persistent store coming from bundle

Tags: iphone, core-data

The Xcode templates for the creation of core data apps start a new blank sqlite file when the app is started the first time. But suppose I have a database already created that I need to include in the bundle, so, when the app starts the first time it already starts with a populated database.

How should I proceed. Ok, I know that I cannot write the database in the bundle, so I have to copy it to the document's directory. I see this is where the sqlite database created by the app itself is already on. So, that's it? I just overwrite the original file with the one in the bundle at the end of my RootViewController's viewDidLoad method?

If this is the way to go, then I need to build a control method that does that just the first time, right?

It must be a simpler way...

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with copying the .sqlite file from the application bundle to the documents directory. I used the approach outlined very thoroughly in [this blog post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/core-data-starting-data.html) by Jeff LaMarche. It deals specifically with providing staring data to an iPhone application, and it worked like a charm in my app.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. But all I needed was the second part of the article, where he modifies the delegate! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Yeah, it sounded like you already had the .sqlite file set up, but I figure too much info was better than to little =)